# How to pass an instantiated Vue component as a prop in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-props

I want to pass an instantiated Vue Component as a prop to antoher component and then render it, like so:

```
<Button :icon=<IconComponent size="25" /> :link="http://wikipedia.org">Click here to visit Wikipedia</Button>
```

This is at least how I would do this in React. How can I achieve the same with Vue?

Comment: Have a look at vuejs slots https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-slots.html

Comment: Thank you @Tracer69 - I have explored slots but the syntax they offer is not what I am after. I literally want to write my component template as shown in the question and I don't feel like the slot syntax achives that. In case I have missed something - could you perhaps share a snippet of code? Thanks!

Comment: VueJS does not support the syntax you want, so you need to use slots. The slot syntax does exactly what you intend to achieve: interweaving content into child components.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use named slots in the child component :

```
<template>
  <button>
    <slot name="icon"></slot>
    <slot></slot>
 </button>
</template>
```

in parent component:

```
<Button  link="http://wikipedia.org">
 <template #icon>
    <IconComponent size="25" />
 </template>
Click here to visit Wikipedia</Button>
```